# How to block detour programs that bypass firewalls?

Tags: firewalls

We setup a ISG-1000 firewall about a month ago with the goal of blocking specific URLs. Please see image file below in which there are 70EA PCs.

Even though we think we blocked specific URLs, some users detour the IP using the `zenmate` program which is some kind of Detour Program!

Are there firewall settings that would help with this? Not quite sure what to try next.

[image]

Comment: so ummm... what?

Comment: If these computers are on your corporate network and under your control, you can just prevent people from installing browser extensions or running unapproved programs by setting the appropriate corporate group policies. You're running into an issue inherent to network-level website blocking in general, which is that it can easily be circumvented using encrypted proxies/VPN services. It is often easier to block such services at the computer level rather than at the network level.

Comment: Just blocking URLs isn't going to work. There is actually *a lot* involved in securing a network from nefarious input.

Comment: Thank you guys.
But I have a question to tlng05.

Among you wrote down, "by setting the appropriate corporate group policies." what is meaning?.. appropriate policy?
Is this method in the Juniper???

Comment: How are the computers currently being managed? Are you the administrator of all of them?

Comment: @tlng05 There are 70EA computers!
I understood your opinion!
Never mind my question:) Thank you..haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to pass data through a firewall and more so if you don't have control of the software installed on the client computers inside the network.

According to [this information](http://software.sonicwall.com/applications/app/index.asp?ev=sig&sigid=10152) zenmate  tunnels the data through a HTTPS connection. And according to [this](http://signatures.juniper.net/documentation/applications/Web%3AAnonymizer%3AZENGUARD-SSL.html) zenguard.biz is the backend server involved in this process. And based on [this information](https://community.aerohive.com/aerohive/topics/zenmate) zenguard.org and zenguard.io domains are involved too. Thus it might be enough to block these sites, both for HTTP and HTTPS. This will of course block all use of zenmate and not only access to the specific URL you want to block. And of course the domains might change in the future because zenmate itself is not interested in being blocked.

But note that blocking zenmate only solves part of the problem. There are other ways to bypass the firewall, like using a SSL-VPN, tunneling with SSH and much more. At the end there is no fully technical solution to block these bypasses. Instead you should make sure that you control which software is installed and have security policies to prohibit use of any firewall bypasses. Then you need to monitor your network for violations and publicly punish everybody who tries to violate these policies so that other users don't even try.

Comment: The old game of Url-filtering-whack-a-mole

Comment: And if you successfully ban zenmate, there's always another waiting in the wings.

Comment: Thanks to your opinion, I have known this is very difficult thing... 
Ah ;( ...
Then,., whenever I block something, another detouring methods are waiting for me...??

Comment: @SK.Kwon: their are enough ways to pass through a firewall for a knowledgeable user. Without a clear security policy, a way to control it and a way to punish violations as deterrence there is not much you can do. Also, users might simple bypass the firewall with phone tethering etc so you need to control the client PC's too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich
Thank you so much!
Hmmm
Anyway, is there NO perfect solution in the world. .. right?

Comment: You can forbid you users to bring personal devices including phones and paper and frisk them (that might be illegal). Then make them work in a Faraday cage, in a bunker, on controlled computers that are re-imaged every days. Even better, you can cut their internet connection. This should be an efficient solution to your problem, unless you want work to be done. Another solution is to forbid your users to browse for porn or whatever and trust them.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward: unfortunately blind trust does usually not work if you have people with conflicting interests. And if you have enough people there are always conflicting interests.

Comment: This is where an explicit proxy can be beneficial. Some of the same pitfalls remain, but one could argue chances of bypassing are reduced. Many explicit proxies support decrypting SSL (MitM style) and categorizing URL's on the fly through real time analysis. Yes, it's true that some firewalls support SSL inspection but usually throughput suffers as a result. Have you subscribed to a category DB like Websense for filtering? If so you should consider blocking all remote/proxy categories. It's not a perfect "catch all" solution, but does get you a little farther down the road.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Of course blind trust does not solve everything, a mixed approach is probably best. However I'm not sure that conflicting interests can be solved manly by software or hardware controls. This is a human problem that might be best solved at the human level, for example by rethinking the company organization. Then, the the network topology can follow this organization. My previous comment was mainly to show that 100% security is not practical (but 0% is no better).

Comment: Thank you guys!
From now on I've had illusion about firewall.
First time I think all I want to block or something like this enables complete using the firewall...
Thanks to your help, I'm growing up!

Finally I have a question.
What is "blind trust"??

Comment: @SK.Kwon: it might be better worded as blindly trusting somebody. I.e. you tell your users that bypassing the firewall is not allowed and you fully trust them to adhere to this security policy and never check if they are worth this trust. This might work for small groups but with larger groups you can no longer blindly trust everybody but must monitor adherence to the security policy and punish violaters to deter future violations.